# OAuth1 PALINTEXT: surprise! ONLY oauth_token is mandatory?

Tags: oauth

let me focus on OAuth1 PALINTEXT auth, normally it involves several items, e.g.,

```
consumer_key
token_key
token_secret
oauth_nonce
oauth_signature
```

But I happened find that I don't need that much items, I just need one item:

```
token_key
```

This is surprising, I have never heard of this simple fact.

**my question is: is this by design? is there anybody have same experience?**

I've followed some OAuth implementations, such as [this one](https://github.com/maas/maas/blob/2.5.1/src/provisioningserver/refresh/maas_api_helper.py#L41)
There are many such implementations, not necessarily be the above one,
I've translated the code to a simple bash script:

```
curl -v -fksSL http://localhost:5240/MAAS/metadata/status/kscpbd -X POST -d '{
...}' -H 'Authorization:OAuth oauth_consumer_key="ghTgW9CHRHUWxVBaBm", oauth_token="xm8FbsATwyBUcLVUBz", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_timestamp="'$(date +%s)'", oauth_nonce="'$(date +%s)'", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="%26wsGnnys99e7Jpyb5tYhGR75PMHVcf3h6"'
```

It works well, using a bunch of related items.

But I happened find that removing all items except `oauth_token` also works.

```
curl -v -fksSL http://localhost:5240/MAAS/metadata/status/kscpbd -X POST -d '{
...}' -H 'Authorization:OAuth oauth_token="xm8FbsATwyBUcLVUBz", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_version="1.0"'
```

Let me paste an actual screenshot:

```
curl -v -fksSL http://localhost:5240/MAAS/metadata/status/kscpbd -X POST -d '{
>             "event_type": "finish",
>             "origin": "origin-test",
>             "description": "description-test'"$(date)"'",
>             "name": "wipe",
>             "result": "FAILURE"
> }' -H 'Authorization:OAuth oauth_token="6ER47VAMWXp9AMVCy5", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_version="1.0"'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5240 (#0)
> POST /MAAS/metadata/status/kscpbd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5240
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:OAuth oauth_token="6ER47VAMWXp9AMVCy5", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_version="1.0"
> Content-Length: 211
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 211 out of 211 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Server: TwistedWeb/17.9.0
< Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 04:55:50 GMT
```

(HTTP 204 is the expected result, not an error).

Comment: I think you are missing the question part of your question.

Comment: @DaImTo I have edited the question, should be easier to understand now.